# Rails 5—How to add UUID column

Tags: mysql, uuid, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

There doesn't seem to be much documentation on `UUID`s in Rails 5. All I've found is this code:

```
create_table :users, id: :uuid do |t|
  t.string :name
end
```

That works great if you're creating a table, but what if you're updating an already-existing table?

How do you *add* a `UUID` column to a table?

Comment: Here is the answers, check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43245416/6059387

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To migrate from default id to use uuid, try writing migration like this:

```
class ChangeProjectsPrimaryKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_column :projects, :uuid, :uuid, default: "uuid_generate_v4()", null: false

     change_table :projects do |t|
       t.remove :id
       t.rename :uuid, :id
     end

     execute "ALTER TABLE projects ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
   end
 end
```

Comment: I got that, but it didn't work, the migration stops and shows this error: `Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uuid DEFAULT 'uuid_generate_v4()' NOT NULL' at line 1: ALTER TABLE 'projects' ADD 'new_id' uuid DEFAULT 'uuid_generate_v4()' NOT NULL`

Comment: This doesn't work with MySQL. MySQL does not define function uuid_generate_v4 nor does it allow using function in DEFAULT (requires constant).

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to add a `uuid` column to an existing Rails table.

```
class AddUuidToContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
     enable_extension 'uuid-ossp' # => http://theworkaround.com/2015/06/12/using-uuids-in-rails.html#postgresql
     add_column :contacts, :uuid, :uuid, default: "uuid_generate_v4()", null: false
     execute "ALTER TABLE contacts ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid);"
  end
end
```

If you forget to add `enable_extension 'uuid-ossp'`, you'll get these errors:

> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not
>   exist ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: 
>   function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist

Comment: You're assuming the OP is using PostgreSQL. He hasn't provided any information about it, but it appears he is actually using MySQL as he posted a MySQL error.